# Make an ajax request based on a variable from another ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have one ajax function that is parsing xml to return the data. Something like :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "the.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success:   function  parseXml(data){
        $(data).find("ITEM").each(function(){
            var x= $("URL", this).text();
            $("#content").append('<div>' + (z) + '</div>');
        }); 
    }
```

Now I need to pass x to a second ajax request before I print it in the content div (the z variable).  Can someone please explain to me how this would work.  My other request would be something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: x,
    data: 'req=exists,json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: s7jsonResponse
});


function s7jsonResponse(response){
     var z = response["catalogRecord.exists"];
}
```

Please forgive the mess, I am just trying to get my question across... thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Define the variable outside of the ajax call first, that way you are changing it on success (as opposed to defining it locally) and it is available to other functions.

Answer (score 0):

You'll also want to make the second call in the success of the first call, and do your append in the success of the second call.